# Preventing non-src code module from running maven build cycle when a source file from another JVM module is run

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I made a maven module that I use only to copy some files around and process them a bit. There is no java or kotlin in it, however it is a JVM-type module. For some reason though, after I did that now, the maven lifecycle runs (I think up to and including phase: package) when I try to jvm projects from other modules. Why is this happening? I just want to be able to run the MVN phases on that module manually.  anyone know how to disable it for this module?

Comment: Please show an example and what kind of module do you have JVM-type module? I don't know what you mean by that?

Comment: JVM-type module just means it has the extra tabs in the Project Structure for the module Paths, Dependencies for running Java or Kotlin. I think it is necessary to be able to run maven on a module.

Comment: You can of course build your modules which contain a module-info.java file with Maven...I don't see the relationship with that? Can you explain more in detail...or best would be an example...

Comment: not really sure how to quickly come up with an example from my code, it is just I have several java/kotlin modules and this non-source module is just a way to store a bunch of related files that I want to have under git and be able to deploy separately, that's the best I can explain it. It works fine except the problem that I have right now is that it makes running any java/kotlin class from my project slower since it first builds this module before running any code from the other modules.

Answer (score 1):

All phases are run against all modules. When you run `mvn package` in your root directory, it runs all the phases from Default lifecycle [[1](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)] up to `package` against every module that's described in your `<modules>`.

But phases don't do anything. They are just labels - and *plugins* are bound to these labels[[2](https://github.com/qala-io/java-course/blob/master/docs/programme/articles/maven-lifecycles-n-phases.md)]. So what's done in a phase is determined by the list of plugins that are bound to that phase.

Things that you may try out:

- Change `packaging` of your module to non-jar. Packaging determines the list of default plugins bindings. This seems to be the best option for you.
- Remove the module from `<modules>` and run whichever plugins you need separately. Thus this module will be excluded completely from your root module.
- Unbind the plugin from your module (if the plugin is inherited from the parent POM) by setting a non-existing phase to it (and all other plugins):

```
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>default-compile</id>
          <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: I have this phase none for both the compiler plugin and the jar plugin. I did this so that I could run the module [package] without it building any jars. It still made an empty classes folder though but I handled that by making the clean plugin run later than in the build process.I did not know about packing pom but that doesn't seem to change anything for me, the module still builds before classes from other modules are run.

Comment: is `<modules>` something that is explicitly defined by the user? I only have that in one pom but that doesn't reference this particular module